# Update value of each row in stored procedure certain id

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, triggers

I want to create a stored procedure that automatically updates the balance of each transaction class after insert, update and delete operations. I have one relation with four attributes, combination between id and transaction_class is the primary key.

Table `Transcation`:

```
Id  Transaction_Class  Credit   Debit    Balance
-------------------------------------------------
1        1               0      100      200
2        2               0      1000     500
3        1               0      100      200
4        3               0      1000     1000
5        2              500     0        500
```

If I ‘INSERT INTO

Comment: Seems incomplete......

Comment: Shouldn't the balance for `transaction_class = 1` be -200 (two debits with 100) and -1000 for `transaction_class = 3`? In general it's not a good idea to store values that can easily be calculated based on the existing values. You can get that result with a single SQL query without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using functions:

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE balances (    
    Id serial,
    Transaction_Class varchar(4),
    Credit float(2),
    Debit float(2),
    Balance float(2)
);
```

Define function (this function sets balance as the difference between credit and debit):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_transaction(t varchar(4),c float(2), d float(2)) 
    RETURNS void AS $$
    BEGIN
      INSERT INTO balances 
      (Transaction_Class,Credit,Debit,Balance)
      VALUES (t,c,d,c-d);
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Insert new data using function:

```
select add_transaction('T',30.5,15);
```